# Prevent the changing size of the site opened with WebBrowser

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, keycode

I want to prevent the size changes of the site opened with WebBrowser.

For example, if you use "CTRL + MWHEELUP" or "CTRL + MWHEELDOWN" combinations on any WebBrowser control, (or any browser) site's size is changes. I want to prevent this.

I have a code, but this code is prevents "CTRL + O" (New address window) and "CTRL + N" (Open with Internet Explorer) combinations only;

```
private void launcherBrowser_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{ if ((e.KeyCode == Keys.N || e.KeyCode == Keys.O) && e.Control) { e.IsInputKey = true; } }
```

I did research for that, but I couldn't find anything. I need your help.

Comment: Taking away a common browser function from a user is generally a really bad idea. People might avoid the page if it breaks their browser. What exactly is the use case?

Comment: @MarkusDeibel, I'm going to use this WebBrowser on a completely different purpose. That's why these combinations have to be block.

Comment: How about handling the [OnMouseWheel event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.onmousewheel?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_Control_OnMouseWheel_System_Windows_Forms_MouseEventArgs_) instead of the PreviewKeyDown? In there you could check if a modifier key is currently in pressed state as well and you're done (at least for the mouse, there is still `Ctrl + +` and `Ctrl + -`)